# UI Save/Restoration mechanism in Cocoa via Swift

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift4, restore, savestate

I'd like to save the state of `Check Box`, quit application, then launch macOS app again to see restored state of my `Check Box`. But there's no restored state in UI of my app.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tick: NSButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
        super.encodeRestorableState(with: coder)
        coder.encode(tick.state, forKey: "")
    }

    override func restoreState(with coder: NSCoder) {
        super.restoreState(with: coder)       
        if let state = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "") as? NSControl.StateValue {
            tick.state = state
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that all the code you've written, because there's a *lot* more to enabling and implementing UI restoration than this. The lynchpin of UI restoration is NSWindow; view controllers do not automatically get included. So you must first make sure your window is getting restored, then that window must take responsibility for preserving and restoring any properties/subviews/controllers that it needs. See [UI Preservation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH3-SW26)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, this is the absolute minimum you need to implement custom UI state restoration of a window and/or its contents.

In this example, I have a window with a checkbox and that checkbox's state represents some custom view state that I want to restore when the app is relaunched.

The project contains a single window with a single checkbox button. The button's value is bound to the `myState` property of the window's content view controller. So, technically, the fact that this is a checkbox control is irrelevant; we're actually going to preserve and restore the `myState` property (the UI takes care of itself).

To make this work, the window's `restorable` property is set to `true` (in the window object inspector) and the window is assigned an identifier (`"PersistentWindow"`). `NSWindow` is subclassed (`PersistentWindow`) and the subclass implements the `restorableStateKeyPaths` property. This property lists the custom properties to be preserved/restored.

Note: if you can define your UI state restoration in terms of a list of key-value compliant property paths, that is (by far) the simplest solution. If not, you must implement `encodeRestorableState` / `restoreState` and are responsible for calling `invalidateRestorableState`.

Here's the custom window class:

```
class PersistentWindow: NSWindow {

    // Custom subclass of window the perserves/restores UI state

    // The simple way to preserve and restore state information is to just declare the key-value paths
    //  of the properties you want preserved/restored; Cocoa does the rest
    override class var restorableStateKeyPaths: [String] {
       return [ "self.contentViewController.myState" ]
       }

    // Alternatively, if you have complex UI state, you can implement these methods
//  override func encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
//      // optional method to encode special/complex view state here
//  }
//  
//  override func restoreState(with coder: NSCoder) {
//      // companion method to decode special/complex view state
//  }

}
```

And here's the (relevant portion) of the content view controller

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @objc var myState : Bool = false

    blah, blah, blah
}
```

(I built this as a Cocoa app project, which I could upload if someone tells me where I could upload it to.)

Comment: Here's a link to download [Persistent UI Swift](https://www.dropbox.com/s/umu9no4ivvbddwz/Persistent%20UI%20Swift.zip?dl=0)

Comment: James, the problem is, application restores its state (for instance for text field) only via Build/Stop buttons in Xcode. There's no `restore state` via Launch/Quit in Finder.

Comment: Make sure you have not checked the **Close windows when quitting app** option in your System Preferences > General settings. Checking that box turns off automatic state restoration globally for all apps.

Comment: And one more observation: using the **Stop** button to stop your app is equivalent to a Force Quit. State restoration may, or may not, work under these conditions. The proper way to test it is to use the **Quit** command to exit the app normally, which allows the `NSApplication` object to performs all of its normal shutdown housekeeping, which includes writing the restoration information to disk.

Comment: Yes, you're right! It works now perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Downloaded project > built > set button to on > quit > launched again from finder > button is off

Comment: Never mind my previous comment: I had restoration disabled in System Preferences.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you don't have to go through `restorableStateKeyPaths` / KVO / KVC if you don't want to.

I was stuck in the same state as you with the `encodeRestorableState()` & `restoreState()` methods not being called but found out what was missing.

1. In System Preferences > General, make sure "Close windows when quitting an app" is unchecked.
2. Make sure that the `NSWindow` containing your view has "Restorable" behavior enabled in IB.
   [image: NSWindow restorable]
3. Make sure that your `NSViewController` has a "Restoration ID" set.
   [image: View controller restoration ID]
4. Your `NSViewController` won't be encoded unless you call `invalidateRestorableState()`. You need to call this each time there's a state in your `NSViewController` that changes and that you want to have saved.
5. When no state changes in the `NSViewController` after having restored it, its state would not be encoded again when closing the app. Which would cause the custom states to not be restored when relaunching the app. The simplest way I found is to also call `invalidateRestorableState()` in `viewDidLoad()`, so that state is always saved.

After doing all that, I didn't even have to additionally implement `NSApplicationDelegate` or `NSWindowRestoration` protocol methods. So the state restoration of the `NSViewController` is pretty self-contained. Only external property is restorable `NSWindow`.

Answer (score 1):

After losing a couple of hours of my life to this problem I finally got it working. Some of the information in the other answers was helpful, some was missing, some was not necessary.

Here is my minimal example based on a new Xcode 13 project:

1. in AppDelegate add *(this is missing in the other examples)*:

   ```
   func applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState(_ app: NSApplication) -> Bool { return true }
   ```
2. in ViewController add:

   ```
   @objc var myState : Bool = false

   override class var restorableStateKeyPaths: [String] {
      return [ "myState" ]
   }
   ```
3. set up some UI and bind it to `myState` to see what is going on
4. make sure System Preferences > General > "Close windows when quitting an app" is unchecked

Things that I **did not** need to do:

- create a custom window subclass
- set a custom restoration id
- it worked fine just with Xcode start/stop